# Linux special shell meaning problems

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I make this code work so that multiplying "*" and mod "%" don't get an error message? I'm thinking is because they have special meaning to the shell. How would I take that away?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Number Operator Number"
echo "[Operators +, -, /, *, %]"
echo -n " --->   "

read num1 op num2

case $op in

  +) printf "$num1 + $num2 = %d\n" `expr $num1 $op $num2`

     ;;

  -) printf "$num1 - $num2 = %d\n" `expr $num1 $op $num2`

     ;;
  /) printf "$num1 / $num2 = %d\n" `expr $num1 $op $num2`

     ;;

  \*) printf "$num1 * $num2 = %d\n" `expr $num1 $op $num2`

     ;;
  %) printf "$num1 % $num2 = %d\n" `expr $num1 $op $num2`

     ;;

  *) echo "Bad Operator: $op choose [+, -, *, /, %]"

     ;;

esac
```

Comment: Quote all your variables, e.g. `"$op"`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to *Arithmetic Expansion* using `$(())`, your entire script could be reduced to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Number Operator Number"
echo "[Operators +, -, /, *, %]"
echo -n " --->   "

read num1 op num2

case "$op" in
    +|-|\*|/|%) echo "$num1 $op $num2 =" $((num1 $op num2)) ;;
    *) echo "Bad Operator: $op choose [+, -, *, /, %]" ;;
esac
```

You can read more about this in the **Arithmetic Expansion** section of `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You should always quote your variables unless you specifically *want* them to undergo word splitting and globbing.

```
case "$op" in
  +) printf "$num1 + $num2 = %d\n" `expr "$num1" "$op" "$num2"`
     ;;
  -) printf "$num1 - $num2 = %d\n" `expr "$num1" "$op" "$num2"`
     ;;
  /) printf "$num1 / $num2 = %d\n" `expr "$num1" "$op" "$num2"`
     ;;
  \*) printf "$num1 * $num2 = %d\n" `expr "$num1" "$op" "$num2"`
     ;;
  %) printf "$num1 % $num2 = %d\n" `expr "$num1" "$op" "$num2"`
     ;;
  *) echo "Bad Operator: $op choose [+, -, *, /, %]"
     ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use the `(( ))` operators.

Your lines should look like:

```
printf "$num1 + $num2 = %d\n" $(( expr $num1 $op $num2 ))
```

And you won't have issues with unquoted variables. :)